# Why is it recording an extra item/line ( ' ' ) in nlist when I only need the lines added my the user?

Tags: python, list, file

Example: I type positive numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4 and then end the first function by typing -1. The list (nlist) displayed in the second function is ['1', '2', '3', '4', '']. Where is this extra fifth item coming from and how do I prevent it?

```
def pos_num():

    # Open num.txt and define num
    num_list = open('num.txt', 'w')
    num = 1

    # While num is positive, ask user for input
    while num >= 0:
        num = int(input('Type + number to add to num_list, - number to end: '))

        # If user input is positive: \
        # convert to str, add to list, convert to int to continue loop
        if num >= 0:
            num = str(num)
            num_list.write(num + '\n')
            num = int(num)

        # If user input is negative: \
        # close num.txt and inform user
        else:
            num_list.close()
            print('List has been written to num.txt')

# Call program 1
pos_num()

# Program 2: Number File Reader
def nfread():

    # Ask user for filename to open
    filename = input('Filename: ')
    infile = open(filename, 'r')

    # Create empty list
    nlist = []

    # Read first line, strip '\n', append to nlist, begin line count
    line = infile.readline()
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    nlist.append(line)
    count = 1

    # While line is not empty: \
    # read line, strip '\n', append line to nlist, add 1 to count
    while line != '':
        line = infile.readline()
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        nlist.append(line)
        count += 1
        print(line, count)

    # Close num.txt
    infile.close()

    # Return nlist
    return nlist
```

Comment: You are not checking whether line is an empty string before adding it to the list. Your while check of whether or not the line is != '' only happens after you append the item to the list.

Comment: replace `infile.readline()` with `infile.read().splitlines()` that will return the list assign that to `nlist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider changing this block:

```
# Read first line, strip '\n', append to nlist, begin line count
line = infile.readline()
line = line.rstrip('\n')
nlist.append(line)
count = 1

# While line is not empty: \
# read line, strip '\n', append line to nlist, add 1 to count
while line != '':
    line = infile.readline()
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    nlist.append(line)
    count += 1
    print(line, count)
```

To something like

```
count = 0
for line in infile:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line:
        nlist.append(line)
        count += 1
        print(line, count)
```

Of all the changes, the one that should fix your program is the addition of `if line:` -- it will cause your program *not* append an empty element to your list (a result of calling `.rstrip()` on just a newline character).

Answer (score 1):

Read the entire file in one go. `read().splitlines()` will remove the line endings

```
def nfread():

    # Ask user for filename to open
    filename = input('Filename: ')
    with open(filename, 'r') as inflile: 
        nlist = inflile.read().splitlines()
        count=len(nlist)
    return nlist
```

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop checks if the current line is not empty, but appends the next line to nlist.  You can fix it by defining the next line before the loop.

```
line = infile.readline()
while line != '':
```